# Responsive CSS img not going to 100% of container width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my images show up 100% within a container, right next to each other. I happen to have a really wide screen so when I go wide, my images don't go 100% of the width of the container they're in. Instead, spaces between the images start creeping in. How do I resolve this?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container-responsive">


<footer>
<div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/but-plan.png" alt="Plan" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/but-administration.png" alt="Administration" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/but-our-team.png" alt="Our Team" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

</div> <!-- container -->

CSS

footer a {
  display:block;
}

footer img {
  max-width:100%; 
  height:auto; 
}

/*******************************************************/
/******************* Helper Classes ********************/
/*******************************************************/

.no-padding {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change max-width to width on your image like so:

```
footer img {
  width:100%; 
  height:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting width to 100% for image, not max-width

Answer (score 0):

Just set your image to take 100%, take into consideration that your image might get pixelated, because it will try to fit the container's width.... 
A work around would be using a huge image(not recommended for performance) or using [srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/)

```css
footer a {
  display:block;
}

footer img {
  width:100%; 
  height:auto; 
}

/*******************************************************/
/******************* Helper Classes ********************/
/*******************************************************/

.no-padding {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-responsive">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<footer>
<div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Plan" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Plan" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 no-padding">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Plan" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

</div> <!-- container -->
```